# I dont want my regex to start with a parenthesis

Tags: python, regex

I have the following regex :

`"F[iI][cgeGCE]?[\.,]?S?[0-9\-]+[A-Z]?[\.,]"` *ex1*

It allows me to detect description of some images, however, in the text i have, they mention figures by putting a parenthesis, so i want to modify this regex so, if there is a parenthesis in front of it like this "(Fig.24..." i don't take it. I tried

`"[^\(]F[iI][cgeGCE]?[\.,]?S?[0-9\-]+[A-Z]?[\.,]"` *ex2*

It didn't worked well because most of the time (but not always), my regex appears in the start of a string, and the *ex2* need any char but "(" in order to work. Is there a way to do what I want ?. Thanks for your attention

Comment: Use `\`` not `**` to format your code, then anti slashes (normally called backslashes) won't disappear.

Comment: I think you could try `(?<!\()F[iI][cgeGCE]?[/.,]?S?[0-9/-]+[A-Z]?[/.,]`

Comment: `([^\(]|^)F[iI][cgeGCE]?[\.,]?S?[0-9\-]+[A-Z]?[\.,]` should work.

Comment: ok tanks !, i'll try @Thefourthbird

Comment: just as some random information for you, there are sites like [regex101](https://regex101.com/) that can help you test regex quickly, with nice visual indicators